# Angular templates and adding active class to menu item

Tags: angularjs

Try to add active class to menu item without using templates and it works. But when I try to add menu with template it breaks.
This code I use for `li` :

```
ng-click="select($index)" 
ng-class="{sel: $index === selectedIndex}"
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.selectedIndex = 0;
$scope.select = function(i) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = i;
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SqHGhm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/wVW1F5HFUgXeaDi3kFyR?p=preview

Edited a few things :

- Changed the sub-template to display the right name for the sub menu
- Changed the `ng-click` instruction to assign to change the selected index

TODO :

- Remove the selected class from the previously selected index